# RPM Spec file conditional Requires per distribution AFTER build

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to build RPM files and I want them to be commonly used and beeing not depending on which distribution is installed. 
Now I found a requirement which name is different on RHEL and SLES. 
I found this as possible solution:

```
%if 0%{?suse_version}
 Requires:       jdk >= 2000:1.8.0_00-fcs, netcat, telnet, at
%else
 Requires:       jdk >= 2000:1.8.0_00-fcs, nc, telnet, at
%endif
```

But my problem with is, that it's an if query for the Build process, what I wish to have is depending on the distribution I install, the already build rpm file would solve this. 
Because with this solution, I would need to build RPM files for every kind of centos and rhel and sles distribution on all these different OSes while only the name of nc and netcat differ as Required packages.

Any idea how I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rpm-4.13 will solve my issue: http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/BooleanDependencies

```
or - requires one of the operands to be fulfilled
Requires: (pkgA >= 3.2 or pkgB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you are asking at install-time. However, you can require the executable itself, e.g. `/bin/netcat` and it should work... unless it was part of the great [UsrMove](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove)...